# Auto-Reloading of textField with correct numbers - iOS

Tags: ios, numbers, uitextfield

I'm building an application that transforms millimeter, centimeters, decimeters, meters, etc...
For this, I put a bunch of `textFields` on my `ViewController` and I want them to auto-reload and calculate the correct answer without making the use of a button.
Example, the user leaves the `millimeters textField` with 200 in it, I want the `centimeters textField` to update itself to 20 (= milliTextField / 100).

I have tried a bunch of method I found online but my `ViewController` is just staying frozen...

Also, I know that an input in a `textField` is a string, so I used the method below to change it into a float, calculate and put it back into the textField as a string... but I have no certitude the code is really doing what I expect it to do...

```
-(void)abaqueBrain
{
    if (_milliTextField != nil)
    {
    float centiValue = [self.milliTextField.text floatValue] / 10.0;
    self.centiTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", centiValue];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
        // etc... (manage the other textFields higher than centimeters)
    }
    else if (_centiTextField !=nil)
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error? Give more information which you guess? With "frozen" I can not imagine

Comment: Sorry, when I said "frozen" is more like unresponsive (but I dont know if its English or just me using a French work at an English way..) - Not reacting, not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `UITextFieldDelegate`; you want to respond to user as he/she types in the textfield.

The `UITextFieldDelegate` provides the following methods:

```
1. textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
2. textFieldDidBeginEditing:
3. textFieldShouldEndEditing:
4. textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

You need to conform to this protocol. When conformed, you'll receive the above mentioned call-back methods to updated the other `View`s in your app.

Comment: Yes, I previously implemented the "textFieldDidBeginEditing:" and "textFieldDidEndEditing:" from the UITextFieldDelegate because I wanted to manage the hidden textFields which were behind the keyboard on iOS when this one was popping up!  But.... I didn't use the 1. and 3.  Do you recommend using one of those?

Comment: The methods are quite self explanatory. Which one to use really depends upon **when** you want to respond to the user.

Comment: I will dig more into Apple's Documentation.  I can differentiate Begin and End, but I am still not fully familiar with Should and Did, etc.  English is also not my first language. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Put little `NSLog` messages in these call-back methods, this way you will get an idea when exactly a method gets called. Play with it till you start feeling comfortable.

Comment: great! Thank you!  It is working in the "didEndEditing".  I dont have the automatisme (yet) that a method can handle multiple purpose of codes.  <br/>The only thing now is that my answer goes all crazy with the zeros after the decimal point (like: 10.000000)

Comment: Convert your decimal value into an integer.

Comment: ok.  I fixed my issue by changing the "%2f" with "%.2f" - Missing a dot in there!